# Count and label observations per participant using loop

Tags: r, loops

I have repeated-measures data.

I need to create a loop that will incrementally count each observation, within a participant, and label it.

I am new to writing loops. My logic was to say, for each item in the list of unique ids, count each row in that, and apply some function to that row.

Could someone point our what I am doing wrong?

```
data$Ob <- 0

for (i in unique(data$id)) {
  count <- 1
  for (u in data[data$id == i,]) {
      data[data$id ==u,]$Ob <- count
      count <- count + 1
      print(count)
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Justin

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Generate some dummy data
data <- data.frame(Ob=0, id=sample(4,20,TRUE))

# Go through every id value
for(i in unique(data$id)){
    # Label observations
    data$Ob[data$id == i] = 1:sum(data$id == i)
}
```

Be aware though that `for` loops are notoriously slow in R. In this simple case they work fine, but should you have millions and millions of rows in your data frame you'd better do something purely vectorized.

Comment: +1 for an inventive solution. I had to look at @Blacklin's solution to understand the question though...

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ave`:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(id = sample(4, 10, TRUE))
data$Ob = ave(data$id, data$id, FUN=seq_along)
data
   id Ob
1   2  1
2   2  2
3   3  1
4   4  1
5   1  1
6   4  2
7   4  3
8   3  2
9   3  3
10  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

But you don't need a loop...

```
data <- data.frame (id = sample (4, 10, TRUE))

##    id
## 1   3
## 2   4
## 3   1
## 4   3
## 5   3
## 6   4
## 7   2
## 8   1
## 9   1
## 10  4

data$Ob  [order (data$id)] <- sequence (table (data$id))

##    id Ob
## 1   3  1
## 2   4  1
## 3   1  1
## 4   3  2
## 5   3  3
## 6   4  2
## 7   2  1
## 8   1  2
## 9   1  3
## 10  4  3
```

(works also with character or factor IDs)

(isn't R just cool!?)